# Is there a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ with $\dim(\ker T)=\dim(\mathrm{im}T)=1$ and $\mathbb R^2=\ker T\oplus\mathrm{im}T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is there a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$ that:
$$\dim (\ker T) = \dim (\operatorname{im} T) = 1$$

and also

$$\mathbb R^2 = \ker T \oplus \operatorname{im} T?$$

Thank you.

Comment: It is almost harder to find a non-example ...

Comment: Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, take $T\colon ℝ^2 → ℝ^2,~(x,y) ↦ (x,0)$. Now what is $\ker T$ and $\operatorname{img} T$?

An important class of examples of such transformations $T$ on a vector space $X$ with the property $V = \ker T \oplus T$ are so-called *projectors*, see wiki/[Projector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)). These are endomorphisms $p$ on a vector space $V$ such that $p^2 = p$. It’s easy to see that, for these, $\ker p ∩ \operatorname{img} p = 0$ and $\ker p + \operatorname{img} p = V$.

Comment: thx but  (x,y)↦x isnt it R2→R1?
sorry for my bad english

Comment: @cstudent1212 Yeah, I’m sorry. I meant $(x,0)$. Already edited.

Comment: in this example u gave,KerT=Span{(0,1)} right?
therefore dim(KerT)=1?

Comment: @cstudent1212 Yes, that’s true.